# how to transfer time Type values from Excel Cell into DGV

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two question about transfering datas from Excel file into Datagridview. So in Excell I have one Column where are only times written, such as: 12:49:40 PM, 11:33:49 AM, 2:27:28 PM ... and this Column has Time Format.
When I am transfering datas into Datagridview with this Code:

```
if (label1.Text != "File isn't Chosen")
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                path = Path.Combine(path, label1.Text);

                string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

                OleDbConnection olcon = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);

                string command = "select * from[Sheet2$]";

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, olcon);
                //Fill Gridview with Datas from Excel
                try
                {
                    olcon.Open();
                    dt.Clear();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

                finally
                {
                    olcon.Close();
                    var totalWidth = dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.None);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File isn't Chosen");
            }
```

In DGV I am getting time + date, such as: "2/26/2017 12:49:40 PM", "2/26/2017 11:33:49 AM", "2/26/2017 2:27:28 PM" and this Date is in every Cell is same. I donn't know why it is doing so but I want just to transfer time, note date.
So first Question: How to transfer only time(without Date) from Excel into DGV
and
second Question: Is it possible to transfer time in 24 hour format? For example:
21:00, 20:00, 17:00 ... (without AM and PM).

Comment: Cell Format and Parse events can be used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have Written:
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
and it works fine